# finding an argument of a complex number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

What is the simplest way to find the argument of the following function?
`((1 - E^((I π (1 - α))/(β - α)) z)/(1 - E^(-((I π (1 - α))/(β - α))) z))`
as I tried the polar way, but it is so complicated and I didn't reach the result yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `z` a real or complex number? Same for $\alpha,\,\beta$.

Comment: z is a complex number while alpha and beta are real numbers . with alpha is less than 1 ,and beta is greater than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one path... define your function and translate to trig form:

```
f[x_, z_] := ExpToTrig[((1 - 
   E^((I π (1 - α))/(β - α)) z)/(1 - 
   E^(-((I π (1 - α))/(β - α))) z))]//. 
        (π (1 - α))/(-α + β) -> x
```

using a replacement of a new real variable x for the more complicated expression involving alphas and betas. This gives `f[x,z]` as

```
 (1 - z Cos[x] - I z Sin[x])/(1 - z Cos[x] + I z Sin[x])
```

Now break this apart so that it has real denominator (using a function from the help files for the `Conjugate` function)

```
 toRealDenominator[rat_] := 
   With[{c = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Denominator[rat]]]}, 
   Expand[Numerator[rat] c]/Expand[Denominator[rat] c]]
```

And so

```
Simplify[toRealDenominator[f[x, z]]]
```

gives a complicated expression. But, since we're only interested in the phase, and the denominator is real-valued, we can just use the `Numerator`. Hence

```
Simplify[Numerator[toRealDenominator[f[x, z]]]]
```

gives

```
(-1 + z Cos[x] + I z Sin[x])^2
```

Now this is something squared, so the phase is 2 times the phase of that something. Hence

```
ComplexExpand[-1 + z Cos[x] + I z Sin[x] //. z -> a + b I]
```

gives the answer

```
-1 + a Cos[x] - b Sin[x] + I (b Cos[x] + a Sin[x])
```

For any z (defined via a and b) and any x (defined via alpha and beta) this is a complex number in the form of A + B I and so you can find its phase using `Arg` or `ArcTan`.

Comment: thank you very much .. I will try the both ways.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to express the solution with Re[z] and Im[z], here is a solution :

```
  ComplexExpand[
 Arg[((1 - E^((I π (1 - α))/(β - α)) z)/(1 - 
      E^(-((I π (1 - α))/(β - α))) z))], {z}, 
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] //Simplify
```

$\text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{1-\text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi  (-2+\alpha +\beta )}{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Im}[z]^2+2 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Re}[z]-\text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi  (-2+\alpha +\beta )}{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Re}[z]^2}{1+\text{Im}[z]^2+2 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Re}[z]+\text{Re}[z]^2-2 \text{Im}[z] \text{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right]},-\frac{2 \left(\text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Im}[z]^2+\text{Re}[z]+\text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Re}[z]^2\right) \text{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right]}{1+\text{Im}[z]^2+2 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right] \text{Re}[z]+\text{Re}[z]^2-2 \text{Im}[z] \text{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi -\pi  \beta }{\alpha -\beta }\right]}\right]$

Answer (score 2):

My idea is first rewriting the complex function to $a+ib$ form then extract the real and imaginary part. So `ComplexExpand` and `Cases` is needed.
Here is my code

```
expr = (1 - E^((I π (1 - α))/(-α + β)) z)/(
  1 - E^(-((I π (1 - α))/(-α + β))) z);

newexpr = expr /. z -> (r E^(I θ));
{realPart, imPart} = First@Cases[ComplexExpand@newexpr, a_ + I b_ :> {a, b}, {0}]
```

The output is very complicated so I will not post here. Then you can calculate the argument.